# A talk with Four Brothers

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, story

Once upon a time, on going to the small park nearby to take some fresh air, I met four quite peculiar brothers and had a talk with them. Each had a different story to tell.

> The first two brothers were racers, and had also ran in the same competition. They both were excellent runners, one came 2nd and the other came 4th. The first brother says, "I can defeat my brother only as I have double power than him, this will be evident from the fact when we will grow up 10 years older." The 2nd brother hesitates and says, "Actually, he is correct. But our heights will be the same".

> Next I had a talk with the next two brothers. They had also raced in the same competition as the first two brothers, and not being good racers, they only came 16th and 17th in the competition. The 3rd brother says, "it doesn't matter why you are asking about our racing, you can compare with our other work. I am a good traveller, and so I can arrive at any place anyone asks me to go to" .

> I had a talk with the fourth brother. He always looked sad, and he said "I am the youngest of the brothers, and people always hate me. I fail to speak English as I got no books, and none of my brothers has a place for me. I don't even have a girlfriend, whereas all my other brothers do. My third brother always gives me a place beside me, but that's all." Also the 2nd Brother has the most popular girlfriend in the town.

Very Peculiar Brothers. I also noticed something strange, although the brothers are the same height :-
The First Brother's Left Hand is longer than the others.
The Second Brother's Right Hand is longer than the others.
The Third Brother's Left Leg is longer than the others.
The Fourth Brother's Right Leg is longer than the others.

Given this information, can you find the names of these four brothers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the four brothers are

> The letters **b, d, p** and **q**

The positions in the competition represent

> The respective positions of the letters in the alphabet

The hands and legs refer to

> The lines extending from the circle in the lower case letters above and below the lines. The extensions upwards on the **b** and **d** are referred to as "hands" while downwards on the **p** and **q** are referred to as "legs".

*I can defeat my brother only as I have double power than him, this will be evident from the fact when we will grow up 10 years older." The 2nd brother hesitates and says, "Actually, he is correct. But our heights will be the same".*

> This refers to the capitalisation of B and D. B has double the bumps but both letters are the same height.

I think GirlFriends refer to

> Adjacent vowels. **b** has **a**, **d** has **e** (the most popular) and **p** has **o** but **q** doesn't have one.

*it doesn't matter why you are asking about our racing, you can compare with our other works. I am a good traveller, and so I can arrive at any place whoever asks me to go to*

> This line I'm unsure about but it could be that **P** represents "Parking" and so you see it a lot travelling or it could simply be that **p** is the first letter of **p**lace.
>  As suggested by Stiv, it could be that the letter **p** can appear at the beginning middle or end of various words, unlike **q**.

Comment: Well done, you got there just before me - was going to post my answer anyway as I had explained the girlfriends already, but you've just edited in so I'll discard mine and give you the +1 instead!

Comment: @Stiv Thanks, I hit post before I realised that I had yet to explain the girlfriends.

Comment: Re the 'good traveller' I was also unsure but my explanation involved the idea that rot13('C' pna nccrne ng gur fgneg, zvqqyr naq raq bs ybgf bs jbeqf, whfg yvxr O naq Q; ohg D pnaabg obnfg guvf rfcrpvnyyl fvapr abg znal jbeqf raq va n D...)

Comment: @Stiv Ah, that might be a better explanation actually.

Comment: Also, 'none of my brothers has a place for me'  may be related to how rot13(D vf nyzbfg arire pbafrphgvir jvgu O, Q be C va na Ratyvfu jbeq). Although there's lots of dressing in the story so it's hard to know exactly what needs explaining and what's just fluff! :)

Comment: @Stiv Yes, I'm also not sure about that bit. The only words I can think of along those lines are rot13("urnqdhnegref", "uvaqdhnegref" naq "fhodhbgvrag") but it seems to be rare, at least.

Comment: Great Job @hexomino for solving this, you will be getting the checkmark :)

Comment: Also @Stiv you are right about rot13(gur cynpr bs gur oebguref) as well as about rot13(gung gur oebgure c vf n tbbq geniryyre.) .

Comment: rot13(d zvtug abg unir n tveysevraq va gur enpr, ohg ur nyjnlf frrzf gb or unatvat bhg jvgu h rireljurer ryfr gurl tb...)